# JQuery children loop XML

Tags: jquery, xml, children

Using JQuery and AJAX, I am getting an XML document and then looping through the document in an attempt to do something at each level of the XML tags/nodes, from parent to children and then children of children respectively.

What i have currently works but is specifically written to a limit of children of children of children (Not ideal).

The final application may have an open ended number of children to do the action to.

`How can i make this account for any number of children without the inefficiency?`

I have tried making a function with the basis of what i wish to achieve at each child level. But this does not work as expected, essentially breaking the script.

**The function**

```
function childX() {
    $(this).children().each(function()
    {
       $("#output").append("<div id='"+(this).nodeName+"'>"+(this).nodeName+"</div><br />");
    });
}
```

**The main script**

```
  $(xml).find("RecentTutorials").children().each(function()
  {

    $("#output").append("<div id='"+(this).nodeName+"'>"+(this).nodeName+"</div><br />");


    $(this).children().each(function()
    {
       $("#output").append("<div id='"+(this).nodeName+"'>"+(this).nodeName+"</div><br />");

      $(this).children().each(function()
        {
           $("#output").append("<div id='"+(this).nodeName+"'>"+(this).nodeName+"</div><br />");

            $(this).children().each(function()
            {
               $("#output").append("<div id='"+(this).nodeName+"'>"+(this).nodeName+"</div><br />");

            });

        });

    });


  //alert((this).nodeName);
  });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to do this would probably be to use a recursive function - that is, a function that calls itself.

```
addChildren( $(xml).find("RecentTutorials") );

function addChildren( $parent ) {
    $parent.children().each( function( i, child ) {
        $("#output").append(
            "<div id='" + child.nodeName + "'>" +
                child.nodeName +
            "</div><br />"
        );
        addChildren( $(child) );
    });
}
```

For an interesting test case, try opening the JavaScript console on any page that uses jQuery - such as the one we are on right now - and paste in this similar code:

```
logChildren( $(document.body) );

function logChildren( $parent ) {
    $parent.children().each( function( i, child ) {
        console.log( child.nodeName );
        logChildren( $(child) );
    });
}
```

It will print the `nodeName` for every element in the page.

BTW I recommend against using `this` and `$(this)` when you use `jQuery.each()`. Instead, use the explicit parameter names as in my examples. It's easier to understand the code this way, and less error-prone too. That is part of the reason your `childX()` function didn't work at all. It references `this` in the first line, but when you call a function directly, `this` is unlikely to be what you expect: unless you're using strict mode, `this` is a reference to the `window` object!

Comment: Ok looking at this now sounds great but i need to jiggle it as it doesnt work directly. Thanks for the direction!

Comment: There was a bug in my first edit of the answer - I left out the `.children()` call! The revised code should work better.

Comment: I have tried both of those and still nothing outputting. I am reading through and do not see what could be the problem.

Comment: There was a typo in the `logChildren()` example. (It was calling `addChildren()` instead of calling itself as I intended.) Try it again in the console and you should see it log the node names.